# mysql select with joins and pivot table

Tags: mysql, join, pivot-table

I have 4 tables: brands, category, brands_category, and files. 
brands and category are linked by brands_category which has 2 columns: brand_id and category_id

```
## brands ##
id  |  name |  url | ..

## category ##
id | name | order | ..

## brands_category ##
brand_id | category_id

## files ##
id | name | path | brand_id | uploaded_at
```

I want to get all distinct brands that are of a certain category and order by uploaded_at from files table without duplication of brands.
I have made quite a few attempts but cant get the results I want.
Here is the most success I've had:

```
SELECT b.*, aa.uploaded_at
   FROM   brands b
   INNER JOIN
  (SELECT   bc.brand_id, f.uploaded_at
               FROM     brands_category bc
                        INNER JOIN brands b
                          ON b.id = bc.brand_id

                        INNER JOIN category c
                          ON c.id = bc.category_id
               INNER JOIN files f
               ON f.brand_id = bc.brand_id
               WHERE    c.id = 1
                GROUP BY bc.brand_id ORDER BY bc.brand_id DESC, f.uploaded_at DESC) aa
       ON b.id = aa.brand_id
```

I do get the brands with category of 1 but the latest uploaded_at date isn't being return when a brand has multiple files associated with it.

Comment: You should post your table structure, sample data and desired results.  How does the `files` table relate to the other tables?

Comment: sorry files relates to brands by a brands_id column on files table

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `pivot` table -- just use standard `joins`:

```
select b.brand_id
from brands b
    join brands_category bc on b.brand_id = bc.brand_id
    join category c on bc.category_id = c.category_id
    join files f on b.brand_id = f.brand_id
where c.category_name = 'Some Category'
order by f.uploaded_at
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thank you it returns all brands but not distinct so many brands are repeated. i also want to select the f.uploaded_at to display on my page. i tried:    select DISTINCT b.* , f.uploaded_at from brands b ... but didnt work

Comment: @Tikaa -- at this point, you'd need to provide sample data and desired results.  I would think `select distinct brandid, uploadedat...` should return your desired results.  If not, you need to specify those results.